# How do I set a user's default .bashrc file?

Tags: bash, users, configuration, home, accounts

On Ubuntu 10.4 I have edited the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file to set some variables like the command history size (`HISTSIZE=5000`), however if I create a new users Ubuntu by default gives them a `.bashrc` file in their home directory with this set as `HISTSIZE=1000` which is overriding mine. How can I change the default `.bashrc` file that is created?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You may put default configurations in /etc/skel so that useradd(8) can copy files in /etc/skel whenever it creates new user's directory by '-m' option.

Note that this is used only for the new-user.  Existing user accounts are not affected.

Comment: If you want to set this up proactively, tell the `.bashrc` file in `/etc/skel/` to source, for instance, `/etc/defaults/bashrc` or whatever file you choose. That still won't prevent users from removing the line in their own `.bashrc` if they want it gone, but.